# Shape sized link in CSS

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, size, shapes

I'm new to CSS and HTML, so it might be a silly question.
I have a shape with a text inside of it. Is there a way to create a shape sized link and not only a text sized one?

See the following image. The entire dark shape should be the link:

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```css
a {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Videos</a>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: something like this? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/GvyZBg

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make your `<a>` tag a block level element with `display: block;`. Now you can apply `width` and `height` properties to create the black rectangle:

```css
a {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size: 2.8em;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 170px;
  padding: 2px 12px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Videos</a>
```